# Json Response in RoR 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this response from a json request

```
{"hashtags"=>[{"text"=>"mytext", "indices"=>[0, 11]}], "urls"=>[], "user_mentions"=>[], "media"=>[{"id"=>174259745790767104, "id_str"=>"174259745790767104", "indices"=>[18, 38], "media_url"=>"http://myurl.com/AmsYUMaCMAAgjlm.jpg", "media_url_https"=>"https://myurl.com/AmsYUMaCMAAgjlm.jpg", "url"=>"http://my.com/6rSti1uE", "display_url"=>"image_url", "expanded_url"=>"http://myurl.com/dir/1", "type"=>"photo", "sizes"=>{"medium"=>{"w"=>600, "h"=>450, "resize"=>"fit"}, "large"=>{"w"=>1024, "h"=>768, "resize"=>"fit"}, "small"=>{"w"=>340, "h"=>255, "resize"=>"fit"}, "thumb"=>{"w"=>150, "h"=>150, "resize"=>"crop"}, "orig"=>{"w"=>1024, "h"=>768, "resize"=>"fit"}}}]}
```

How can i get the value of the media_url_https field?

Answer (score 1):

media_url_https = myHash["media"][0]["media_url_https"]

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to a variable

```
json = {"hashtags"=>[{"text"=>"mytext", "indices"=>[0, 11]}], "urls"=>[], "user_mentions"=>[], "media"=>[{"id"=>174259745790767104, "id_str"=>"174259745790767104", "indices"=>[18, 38], "media_url"=>"http://myurl.com/AmsYUMaCMAAgjlm.jpg", "media_url_https"=>"https://myurl.com/AmsYUMaCMAAgjlm.jpg", "url"=>"http://my.com/6rSti1uE", "display_url"=>"image_url", "expanded_url"=>"http://myurl.com/dir/1", "type"=>"photo", "sizes"=>{"medium"=>{"w"=>600, "h"=>450, "resize"=>"fit"}, "large"=>{"w"=>1024, "h"=>768, "resize"=>"fit"}, "small"=>{"w"=>340, "h"=>255, "resize"=>"fit"}, "thumb"=>{"w"=>150, "h"=>150, "resize"=>"crop"}, "orig"=>{"w"=>1024, "h"=>768, "resize"=>"fit"}}}]}
```

then

```
media_url_https = json["media"][0]["media_url_https"]
```

should do it.

Comment: this is what i do

url = Hash.new
            url = item["entities"]
            media_url_https = url["media"][0]["media_url_https"]
            Rails.logger.debug media_url_https.inspect

I get a nil value when i didnt expect it. Am i doing smth wrong?

Comment: Ruby's dynamically typed, you don't need the first url = Hash.new.

Comment: I don't know what `item` is so without seeing that I can't tell you why you're not accessing the variable you want.

Comment: Thanks everybody it was a syntax error.I have the app working now. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

First you should convert it from hash to json string,
Then in your page, you should decode it by using javascript(jquery or ext), if you don't use jquery or ext, you can decode it by 'eval' method, then you can access media_url_https via json.

```
var json = eval(yourResponse);
var media_url_https = json['media'][0]['media_url_https'];
```

The above code should solved your question！

Comment: I tried all of those but this is a rake task so i cant use any jQuery in there